# getting error when making Function: Error in value.var %in% names(data) : object 'x' not found

Tags: r, list, function, reshape2

There is something wrong in my function getting error:

Here is the code:

```
fun <- function(x){
        reshape2::dcast(x, formula = PROVINCE + DISTRICT ~ DAILY_LANG,
                        value.var = "WEIGHT", fun.aggregate = sum)
}
```

By running the code getting this error:

```
Error in value.var %in% names(data) : object 'x' not found
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: You must create an object with name x like `x <- ...` to be able to do `result <- fun(x)`

Comment: Would you have a dataset example ? I don't have any error with your code

Comment: What exactly does "running the code" mean?

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/8107362). Especially, provide some sample data, e.g. with `dput()` and use the [reprex-package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/).